# How to add new object of model in a foreign controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am rather new to Rails.

I am working on a profile-page for a `User`. The `show` view is divided into partials. The thing about my modelling structure is, that a `User` can have a `Skill`. But the `User` model itself does not have a `Skill` related column, so all `Skill` entries are saved in the `Skill` model.

So, my question is, how can I include a partial into the `User` `show` view, that contains a simple add `Skill` form (name needed only), which saves that Skill into its own table and adds it to the collection of the current `User.skills`?

Answer (score 0):

in `User#show` create a `@skill = Skill.new` which you can use in your views.

then in you partial you can do

```
<%= form_for(@skill), ... %>
```

see more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: for that you have to create a nested resource in your routes.rb file (assuming `User` `has_many :skills` and `Skill` `belongs_to :user`).

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your problem. You could define a form in the partial and in the controller's action you would have to simply save the Skill and associate the user's id to it. I hope you know that the the Skill model must belong_to User and there should be a user_id column in the skills table to create the association. Even though I am writing a sample code for creating association below.

```
skill = Skill.new
user.skill << skill #Add association for user and skill
#Add skill related info from params into the skill model object
skill.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the partial o the form at skill/_form.html.erb you can do:

```
<%= render "skills/form", skill: @skill %>
```

on the view, and you must add

```
@skill = Skill.new
```

on the show action of your Profile controller. To save that skill, you must do that on your update action on the Profile controller:

```
@skill = Skill.create(params[:skill])
@user.skills < @skill
@user.save
```